# /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no fan-capable sensor modules installed

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-drivers, fancontrol

I know that there are some threads to deal about this topic but neither has helped me. The problem is that the fan of the **graphic-board** permanently runs. I used ArchLinux on the same hardware without any problems but recently I changed to Ubuntu 16.04. Since then I have this problem with my noise fan!!

Here are some hardware informations :

```
**lshw -C system,display,cpu**  
linux-desktop               
    description: Computer  
    width: 64 bits  
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 vsyscall32  
  **CPU** 
       product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU         550  @ 3.20GHz  
       vendor: Intel Corp.  
       physical id: 1  
       bus info: cpu@0  
       size: 1467MHz  
       capacity: 3200MHz  
       width: 64 bits  
       capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm arat cpufreq  
  **Graphic**
       description: VGA compatible controller  
       product: GF108 [GeForce GT 630]  
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation  
       physical id: 0  
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0  
       version: a1  
       width: 64 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom  
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0  
       resources: irq:34 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:d8000000-dfffffff   memory:d6000000-d7ffffff ioport:dc00(size=128) memory:fbe80000-fbefffff    

**cat /etc/modules**   
coretemp  

**dmidecode**  noticed that ACPI is supported! My fan has a connector with four pins (pwa capable).  

**hddtemp** is installed.

**Graphic**
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 630] [10de:0f00] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])  
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. GF108 [GeForce GT 630]   [19da:6199]  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34  
    Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]  
    Memory at d8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]  
    Memory at d6000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]  
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=128]  
    Expansion ROM at fbe80000 [disabled] [size=512K]  
    Capabilities:   
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau  
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau  

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0bea] (rev a1)  

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes  
**BIOS Information** 
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.  
    Version: A7708MLN.105  
    Release Date: 09/21/2010  
    Address: 0xF0000  
    Runtime Size: 64 kB  
    ROM Size: 2048 kB  
    Characteristics:  
        ISA is supported  
        PCI is supported  
        PNP is supported  
        APM is supported  
        BIOS is upgradeable  
        BIOS shadowing is allowed  
        ESCD support is available  
        Boot from CD is supported  
        Selectable boot is supported  
        BIOS ROM is socketed  
        EDD is supported  
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)  
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)  
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)  
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)  
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)  
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)  
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)  
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)  
        ACPI is supported  
        USB legacy is supported  
        LS-120 boot is supported  
        ATAPI Zip drive boot is supported  
        BIOS boot specification is supported  
        Targeted content distribution is supported  
    BIOS Revision: 8.15  

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes  
**System Information**  
    Manufacturer: MEDIONPC  
    Product Name: MS-7708  
    Version: 1.2  
    Serial Number:    
    UUID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-6C626D8F9A68  
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch  
    SKU Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.  
    Family: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In **/etc/default/grub** the entry `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_enforce_resources=lax"` is available.

Comment: **sensors**  
nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +39.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +35.0°C  (high = +89.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:       +33.0°C  (high = +89.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the make and model number of your system, or if a PC the make and model of the motherboard. Also state which fan is making the noise: the CPU fan, the case fan or the graphics card fan. Check it is the correct fan by stopping it for a few seconds by touching its centre.

Comment: Hi Steve! I add the necessary information above. If I touch the fan it stopped and after releasing it starts again.

Answer (score 1):

Change your graphics card driver from the Xorg driver `nouveau` to the proprietary Nvidea driver.

If this does not resolve your problem then follow the instructions to enable custom Nvidia graphics card thermal management [NVidea fan speed tutorial](http://www.upubuntu.com/2015/05/how-to-controladjust-gpu-fan-speed-for.html)